# Fixed position element with 100% width goes beyond parent container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the `display: flex` with `position: fixed` to have width of the same size of its parent. However, with my below code that exceeds the parent container.

Here is what I have already tried. Please check fiddle below

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="items"></div>
    <div class="items"></div>
    <div class="items"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is that the `.flex` container should have the same width of its parent `.container` when I set it to `width: 100%` with `position: fixed`.

Comment: `position: fixed` basically tells your element to ignore every parent except window.

Comment: @Adam I understand that but how can I make it work with flex boxes. New to flexboxes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @so_user - be a bit more specific about what you're trying to achieve. It's not obvious. Keep in mind that `display: flex` only makes something a flex container, so that's is children can obey `flex` properties. It doesn't actually modify anything in particular about the element `display: flex` has been applied to. EDIT: You'll probably find this helpful if you're new to flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You can't use `position:fixed` since it will **ignore** the parent container. We need to know **why** you need to use `position:fixed`.

Comment: *What I want is that the .flex container should have the same width of its parent .container when I set it to width: 100% with position: fixed.* This is not what you want, this is what you did and you don't like the result. Explain your goal

Comment: @TemaniAfif I mean thats what I tried but as you can see the result is not what I was expecting. The width of `.flex` takes the width of the document.

Comment: *you* don't expect this but it's the correct result. This is how position:fixed works and this is why we are asking you to explain what you want.

Comment: @Paulie_D I want this to use for a container to be fixed on the screen while I scroll the rest of the contents. `.flex` width should have the same width as its parent container. because currently it goes beyond its parent container and the document I am working on.

Comment: So, see my answer below which will solve most (if not all) of these issues.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position:sticky` instead

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200vh;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="items"></div>
    <div class="items"></div>
    <div class="items"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and `width;100%` will become useless

Comment: sticky does not seem to provide the same result. It does not stick the .flex to the screen while scrolling the rest of the contents.

Comment: @so_user That's exactly what it's doing. Is `.flex` moving? No...so that would seem to solve the issue.

Comment: As you can see it scrolls everything including .flex. https://jsfiddle.net/xpjm2yk8/1/

Comment: It does move a little in your solution. How can we stop that?

Comment: As you can see there is a header at the top.

Comment: @so_user I think with sticky you need to define some anchor like "top: 0" to simulate the "position:fixed" behavior

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `position:sticky` you can consider `inherit` if the parent will always have a width defined as length and not percentage:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: inherit;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="items"></div>
    <div class="items"></div>
    <div class="items"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```